# Map values onto others

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I've got a value `d` which can be between 0 and `maxD` and a list `l` containing chars, specifically this:

```
list("$@B%8&WM#*oahkbdpqwmZO0QLCJUYXzcvunxrjft/\|()1{}[]?-_+~<>i!lI;:,"^`'. ")
```

I would like to write a function that returns one element of `l` in Dependance with `d` and `maxD`. `maxD` may be bigger or smaller than `len(l)`.

This is about what I'd like, but in correct:

```
def mapChar(d, maxD):
    return l[maxD/d*len(l)]
```

I'm rendering 3d objects in the console and this function will take the distance to a point `d` and the render distance `maxD` and return the ASCII shadeing value from the list.
With what logic could I implement that?

Comment: Do you have a *question*?

Comment: Woaps it chopped of the lower part of my question. Don't know how that happened.

Comment: I think you just want `d/maxD` rather than `maxD/d`; you basically want to solve `x/len(l) == d/maxD` for `x`.

Comment: `x` has to be an `int`, in which case you'll want `d // maxD` if both values are `int`s, or `int(d/maxD)` if either can be a `float`.

Comment: ```d``` and ```maxD``` are both int. So I would do ```l[d//maxD*len(l)]```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found `l[d*len(l)//maxD]` to work.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27642667)

Comment: Nobody suggested this answer. It is inspired by  "chepner "s comment.

Comment: This is completely optional, and really just a matter of etiquette, but when posting an answer on behalf of a commenter, I will often mark my answer as a community wiki, since it's not my original contribution. Regardless, I appreciate elevating the correct answer from the comments to an answer so that the question can be marked as answered.